# Matplotlib custom diverging gradient ignoring colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I've been working on some data plotting functioning for python and one such tool I need for my research is a set of difference charts to compare the changes between two sets of data.

I'm now at the point where I want to plot my data and I was looking into creating custom color maps to handle the diverging data, however all of my plots such far are either ignoring specific steps in my gradient, or the colors are being repeated for my low values.

Here's an example plot that was generated:

[image]

And the code for both my custom color map, as well as the plotting:

```
diffmap_17 = ["#FF0000", "#F81318", "#F12731", "#EB3B4A", "#EB5C66", "#EB7D82", "#EB9E9E", "#F1BEBE", "#F8DEDE", "#FFFFFF", "#DDDCFD", "#BCB9FB", "#9B96FA", "#6A6CFA", "#3A43FA", "#1D21FC", "#0000FF"]
diffmap_17_colormap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(diffmap_17)

contour_levels = [-20, -10, -5, -2, -1, -0.75, -0.5, -0.25, -0.1, 0.0, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20]
cs = m.contourf(x,y,data,contour_levels,cmap=diffmap_17_colormap) #plot total
```

My goal is to have the color map have the zero point be white, and then diverge outward (Reds negative, blues positive). For the time being, I'm employing a standard colormap, however using a custom one would be preferred moving forward.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your data is probably not what you believe it is. Hard to help without a [mcve]...

Comment: I agree with @Julien. From what you show in your picture, you probably have a few extreme values that are hard to see and all the rest of your data are in the range between -1 and 1. Have you tried changing the limits (`vmin` and `vmax`). Also, if your data is in one of the standard formats like netcdf, there are a lot of tools around, which help you quickly look at your files. For netcdf files, for instance, I like to pre-check my data with `ncview`.

Comment: Unlike the comments by @Thomas and Julien suggest, the problem is primarily independent on the data, since the levels are explicitely specified. It is purely a matter of how to define the range of colors to use. Two options are shown in my answer below. The fact that the complete map is the same color however would then also allow for more tight levels (ranging from -10 to 10 would probably be enough). Mind though that Julien is completely right in saying that a [mcve] should be given when asking a question like this (please remember for next time asking).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the colors are chosen from the colormap by dividing the range between the minimum and maximum values into equal parts. Since most levels lie very close to each other, they fall into the same range and thus have the same color.

The easiest solution is not to use a colormap, but a plot where each of the levels gets its color from the colorlist. In this case you may provide the list of colors directly to the `contourf` plot.

```
plt.contourf(x,y,data,contour_levels,colors=diffmap_17)
```

Note, that because you have 19 levels your list would then need 18 colors (I therefore added one).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors

x, y= np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-3,3), np.linspace(-3,3))
r = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)
data = np.tan((r*0.7-1.5))*1.3

diffmap_17 = ["#FF0000", "#F81318", "#F12731", "#EB3B4A", "#EB5C66", "#EB7D82", 
              "#EB9E9E", "#F1BEBE", "#F8DEDE", "#FFFFFF", "#DDDCFD", "#BCB9FB", 
              "#9B96FA", "#6A6CFA", "#3A43FA", "#1D21FC", "#0000FF", "#0000ce"]

contour_levels = [-20, -10, -5, -2, -1, -0.75, -0.5, -0.25, -0.1, 0.0, 
                  0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20]
cs = plt.contourf(x,y,data,contour_levels,colors=diffmap_17)

plt.colorbar(cs)

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you want to use a colormap instead, you would need to provide a normalization instance together with the colormap. A `matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm` would chose the colors according to the list of boundaries supplied to it, which would be the list of levels for the contour plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors

x, y= np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-3,3), np.linspace(-3,3))
r = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)
data = np.tan((r*0.7-1.5))*1.3

diffmap_17 = ["#FF0000", "#F81318", "#F12731", "#EB3B4A", "#EB5C66", "#EB7D82", 
              "#EB9E9E", "#F1BEBE", "#F8DEDE", "#FFFFFF", "#DDDCFD", "#BCB9FB", 
              "#9B96FA", "#6A6CFA", "#3A43FA", "#1D21FC", "#0000FF", "#0000ce"]
diffmap_17_colormap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(diffmap_17)

contour_levels = [-20, -10, -5, -2, -1, -0.75, -0.5, -0.25, -0.1, 0.0, 
                  0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20]
norm = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(contour_levels, diffmap_17_colormap.N)
cs = plt.contourf(x,y,data,contour_levels,cmap=diffmap_17_colormap, norm=norm)

plt.colorbar(cs)

plt.show()
```

The output plot is the same as above.

Comment: I think the reason why the OP had only 17 color levels is because he wants the levels 'centered on the colours', i.e. the actual contour levels would be between the levels defined and then the ticks on the colour bar as they are now -- this is at least what I would want. This very often makes sense especially for the white level, as then 'negligible' (close to zero) values would not show a tendency. Maybe the OP can comment on that ... Anyway +1 from me.

Comment: @Thomas Correct, putting the boundaries symmetrically around zero may often make more sense; but for that one would indeed need to start interpreting the data and at that point I'm already lost in how far there can be negative precipitation (could be that if more water evaporates than rain falls or so and then showing the tendency could indeed be desired).

Comment: What the OP shows is a difference plot -- two model runs with different setups or possibly different algorithms to compute precipitation amount. You do something like this quite frequently when developing such models. Anyway, you are right, it's quite outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a bunch!